# Change hardcoded file path to user prompted in VBA?

Tags: vba, user-input

Right now, I have a VBA macro for Word which parses a document for a certain font and outputs all font of the selected type to a text file.

The hard coded line which I open the text file is something like this:

```
Open "C:\Documents and Settings\Output.txt" For Output As #n
```

Can I change this so the user is prompted to enter the file path at this point in the macro? Something like:

```
Open (PROMPTS USER FOR FILE PATH HERE) For Output As #n
```

Sorry if this seems trivial. I am new to VBA coding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two ways:

**Simple**

```
Dim path As String

path = InputBox("Enter a file path", "Title Here")
Open path For Output As #1
Close #1
```

**With File Chooser**

```
Dim path As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

If path <> "" Then
    Open path For Output As #n
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint on using Application.FileDialog - For reference users can see this article: [Use the File dialog box in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824272) (support.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `InputBox` function.

```
Open InputBox("Enter a file path", "Title", "default path") For Output As #n
```

Comment: There is no Prompt function in VBA